# Snapping point to point nearest to it in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, arcgis-10.3, proximity

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

I have 2 point features *centroid* and *station*. I want to snap all the points of *centroid* to the nearest point in *station* such that *centroid* is only snapped with points of *station*.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: I am using ArcGIS 10.3 for desktop

Comment: Welcome.  Please take the tour here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour  and [edit] your question/tags with software that you are using

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the [Snap tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000007000000), which needs either standard or advanced license level to snap your centroids to your station...

Another (older) way to do this is (in ArcMap, it's not so good in catalog except in model builder):

[Add XY coordinates](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000032000000) to your Station then [Spatial join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) your centroids to your nearest station (within a distance). Now your joined points have all the attributes of centroid and station so Create Feature Class from XY Table either by right clicking on the table in catalog or [Make Event Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006z000000) and saving/exporting with a tool like [copy features](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000035000000) or right click on layer and data/export.

Comment: The snap tool does indeed work for snapping points to points.